# Rename items from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in a dataset which I faced the following situation:

```
df2['Shape'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
Round       0.574907
Princess    0.093665
Oval        0.082609
Emerald     0.068820
Radiant     0.059752
Pear        0.041739
Marquise    0.029938
Asscher     0.024099
Cushion     0.010807
Marwuise    0.005342
Uncut       0.004720
Marquis     0.003602
Name: Shape, dtype: float64
```

and my goal is to make the variables 'Marquis' and 'Marwise' be included into the variable 'Marquise'. How can I combine they?

Comment: Please clarify your question with an example. Your example should consist of the output you get and your desired output.

Comment: Do you want Marquis and Marwise columns to be added together?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't state any restrictions, a quick fix will be that you can first change the entries the way you desire as shown below-

```
df2['Shape'][df2['Shape'] == 'Marquis'] = 'Marquise'
df2['Shape'][df2['Shape'] == 'Marwise'] = 'Marquise'
```

Now, run this command,

```
df2['Shape'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of *row masking* inside pandas `DataFrame.loc`.

Here, at frist row, I want the rows with the mask of "having their shapes to be equal to `Marquis`". So, putting this  *row masking*  along with the `shape` column inside `DataFrame.loc`, I will obtain the result.
Just repeat the same code for `Marwise`.

```
df2.loc[df2['Shape'] == 'Marquis', 'Shape'] = 'Marquise'
df2.loc[df2['Shape'] == 'Marwise', 'Shape'] = 'Marquise'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> s = ['a', 'A', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'd', 'A']
>>> s = pd.Series(s).replace({'a' : 'changed', 'A' : 'changed'})
>>> s

0    changed
1    changed
2    changed
3          b
4          c
5    changed
6          d
7    changed
dtype: object
```